# how to validate BigDecimal in a range?

Tags: java, hibernate-validator

I want to validate a bigDecimal with max 17 integers and 2 fractions, I used `@Digits(integer=17, fraction=2)` but this does not accept 1.10 for example, and `@DecimalMin("0.00")    @DecimalMax("99999999999999999.99")` accepts for example 10.1234.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 0):

@Digits is the way to go.

What's your exact issue with 1.10? I don't see why it would be reported as invalid.

With @Digits(integer=17, fraction=2), you allow **at most** 2 fraction numbers so 1.10 should be OK. If not, we have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is right, so the error must be found elsewhere. For instance:

```
new BigDecimal(1.10)             // ERROR
```

should be

```
new BigDecimal("1.10")
```

The reason to avoid the constructor on a double, is that a double value has no precision (fraction decimals) and is an approximation of powers of 2. 1.10 is in effect an infinite series of (negative) powers of 2.

With the second constructor the BigDecimal becomes a *scale* of 2 = 2 fractional digits.

1.10 is the same as 1.1 and is likely to have a scale > 2, the default scale of double.